# Python Image Library can't convert to pdf

Tags: python, pdf, python-imaging-library

I have a function to convert a bmp to pdf with PILLOW, this script I have it in non compiled version and compiled version (.exe). In the first one it works correctly, but in the second PILLOW throws an exception ('PDF'). Specifically fails in the .save ()
Paths and filename with extension are correct.

```
from PIL import Image
def bmp2pdf(self, file):
    ''' Convert a bmp file to PDF file, and delete old bmp file '''
    img = Image.open(file)
    output = file.replace('.bmp', '.pdf')
    try:
        img.save(output, "PDF", resolution=100.0)
        remove(file)
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
```

In the compiled version the output is:

```
'PDF'
```

Thx.

Comment: What's the full exception?

Comment: Compiled in what way? Have you packaged the dependencies with it?

Comment: I have used CX_freeze to compiled. And I have import: 'PIL.Image'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add in my setup to generate the .exe I should import PIL and not PIL.IMAGE, so the whole module is loaded and the pdf feature is available

I'm using cx_freeze:

```
'Packages': [
    'PyQt5.uic',
    "...",
    'PIL',
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow this code.It works. 3 line code.

`from PIL import Image
def bmp2pdf(self,path):
    img = Image.open(path)
    img.save('image.pdf','pdf')`

I got a file named image.pdf with the image in it.

Comment: Yes, but if you look at my code does the same thing simply that I remove from the system the bmp. It works for me. The only thing in the .exe is not!